# Your sound library recommendations 

Tags: library, sfx, library-sound-effects

Hey guys, searched the forum and noticed we still don´t have a thread that gathers up the very best from sound libraries to a single place accompanied by your recommendation and brief explanation why people should by the library. I´ll start with one of my personal favorite:

The Recordist libraries - Guns HD

Absolutely fantastic sounding stuff with a very reasonable price tag between 50-200 dollars is just too good to miss. Good addition to seasoned audio veteran and a good starter library for those who are just starting their audio careers. We´ve got the bullets library and I´m absolutely certain that we will expand our Recordist collection with gunscapes and machine guns libraries. Check out the samples from recordist website. Good stuff.

http://www.therecordist.com/category/guns-hd

My rating: 4.5 / 5

Comment: Samples From Mars

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Sound Ideas' libraries. They're not cheap and they seem pretty dated, but they are very useful for your productions. I also recommend Japanese SFX libraries like Datacraft's Otojiten series. You can find them on Designpocket, a Japanese shopping website.

I give Sound Ideas' libraries a 4.8/5 and the Otojiten series a 5/5.